# Sources referenced as אר"ח ח"ב and קונדרסים

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, acronyms

I'm reading an article in Encyclopedia Talmudit (*Cherem א*) and finding it a bit difficult to trace its sources. The ones I'm struggling with are described as below. Can anyone help me with full names and, if possible, where to find them online?

- עי' ערוך ע' היסת, שכ"כ בשבועה (ע"ע)
- המאורות מו"ק עמ' מט
- אר"ח ח"ב עמ' 502
- קונדרסים סוף שער ג בד' הרמב"ם

Comment: Sefer Hameorot was written by the Meili https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99

Comment: Which footnote # references קונדרסים סוף שער ג בד' הרמב"ם?

Comment: @IsraelReader In the edition I'm using, that's footnote 34, and קונדרסים alone also appears in footnotes 41, 42, 43, 54 and 59.

Comment: The Beis Yosef (YD334) cites the קונדריסין extensively, regarding הלכות נדוי וחרם. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%93#בית_יוסף

Comment: It seem that a certain Rabbi זק"ש published the קונדריסין in the end of קובץ ראשונים למועד קטן.

Comment: @IsraelReader This is so helpful - any clue on how I find a copy of that last one?

Comment: **Google Books** https://books.google.co.il/books/about/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%95.html?id=hFg9mAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y **Lehmanns** https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/qvbc-rawvnim-mved-qtn.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

עי' ערוך ע' היסת, שכ"כ בשבועה (ע"ע) = [ספר הערוך לר' נתן בן יחיאל מרומי, ערך הסת](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43084&pgnum=98)

Starts on bottom of page, and continues to the next page. The footnote in Encyclopedia Talmudit means that the Aruch wrote this regarding "Shevua" (an oath) [and cross-references to the (as yet unpublished) entry on "Shevua".

[המאורות מו"ק עמ' מט = ספר המאורות לר' מאיר  המעילי, מנרבונה, מסכת מועד  קטן (טז א), עמוד מט](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16149&st=&pgnum=48)

[אר"ח ח"ב עמ' 502 = ספר ארחות חיים לר' אהרן הכהן מלוניל, עמוד 502](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8757&pgnum=558)